# What is a good adjustable ring hook for attaching resistance bands?

Tags: tools

I would like to have an adjustable ring on the wall for attaching ropes and other things. My gym has such a thing, but I can't find it online and could really use some help. Below is an image of the ring hook and it has a switch that allows you to hook it into some kind of wall mount structure. Any ideas?

[image: Ring Hook]

Comment: That looks like a tie down from a cargo management system. Like for box trucks and trailers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an E track tie down system that is commonly used in box trucks and trailers.

Example : [E tracks and assorted tie downs](http://www.uscargocontrol.com/Van-Trailer-Products/E-Track-Straps-Tie-Downs)

Comment: Yes! This looks right. Seems to be this one: http://www.uscargocontrol.com/Van-Trailer-Products/E-Track-Straps-Tie-Downs/E-Track-Tie-Down-W-Round-Ring-Heavy-Duty